# How to use environment variables in a node config file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Given I have an environment variable $KEY

I am running

```
KEY=$KEY babel-node build.js //with webpack I make a bundle of my code
```

My problem is that in js files that webpack bundles there is import to a config.js file.

the config.js looks like this:

```
export default {
  key: process.env.KEY;
};
```

When the value is used in the bundle the key is undefined.

How can I achieve this kind of behaviour. (something like actually overwriting the value config.js with the environment variables and then bundle them with webpack) ?

Comment: What OS are you running on? Is $KEY defined in your shell environment?

Comment: yes...you can even ignore that. even if I do KEY='harcodedValue' i get the same thing. (the app runs in node)

Comment: perhaps try using a package like `dotenv` or `node-config`. If there is something wrong with the way you have the variables set or your setup, doing it a different way may fix the issue

Comment: if you are already using node-config, are you including it in your code? `var config = require('config');` Also read though this to make sure you're doing the right steps for it to work with webpack https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Webpack-Usage

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) which exposes for the bundle the specified env variables.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   KEY: JSON.stringify('process.env.KEY')
});
```